# bash 4.1.2(2): how to apply regex inverse matching in a for-loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, glob, inverse-match

I want to loop through only the directories that do NOT contain string "unicredit". Given this directory list (located in `/tmp/scripts/bash/test/`):

```
par_q
swx_i
swx_r
unicreditucispa_ams_b
unicreditucispa_ams_m
unicreditucispa_ber_b
```

I launched the following one-liner:

```
for i in /tmp/scripts/bash/test/^((?!unicredit*).)*$; do echo FOUND $i; done
```

And expected the following output:

```
FOUND par_q
FOUND swx_i
FOUND swx_r
```

But instead got this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I attempted to escape some/all parentheses with `\` and also tried to enclose the regex with quotes, but it did not solve the problem.

What amendments should I do in order to get the output that I desire?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
shopt -s extglob # enable extglob
for i in /tmp/scripts/bash/test/!(*unicredit*); do echo "FOUND $i"; done
```